# Unable to exchange encryption keys

Tags: php, linux, windows, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm facing a hard problem at the moment and I didn't find anything online that can help me.

I want to connect from my server to another one through SSH in order to send instructions (the second server manage Wi-Fi authorizations).

As much as I can say, I think the problem occurred because we updated one server. (I'm not really sure if the problem has appeared because of it).

I'm from a Windows Server and I want to call a Linux one.

Here is the script :

```
function executeCommand($command) {
    $infoConnection = getInfoConnection();

    $out = '';
    //The Warning occurs here, impossible to go further
    $connection = ssh2_connect($infoConnection["hostname"], 22);

    if ($connection === false) {
        $error = error_get_last();
        throw new Exception("
        Error Type : ".$error["type"]."<br/>
        Message : ".$error["message"]."<br/>
        File : ".$error["file"]."<br/>
        Line : ".$error["line"]."<br/>");
    }

    ssh2_auth_password($connection, $infoConnection["username"], $infoConnection["password"]);

    $stdio_stream = ssh2_shell($connection);
    sleep(2);
    fwrite($stdio_stream,$infoConnection["username"]."\n");
    sleep(1);
    fwrite($stdio_stream,$infoConnection["password"]."\n");
    sleep(1);

    fwrite($stdio_stream, $command."\n");
    sleep(1);
    while($buffer = fgets($stdio_stream)) {

        $out .= $buffer;
    }
    fwrite($stdio_stream, 'exit');
    unset($connection);

    return $out;
}
```

Here is the warning :

> Warning: ssh2_connect() [function.ssh2-connect]: Error starting up SSH connection(-5): Unable to exchange encryption keys in ../aff_wifi.php on line 203

The line 203 is this one :

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($infoConnection["hostname"], 22);
```

When I "catch" the warning, I have this :

> Error type : 2 Message : ssh2_connect() [function.ssh2-connect]:
>   Unable to connect to ipAdress
>   File: ..\aff_wifi.php 
>   Line: 203

Do you have any idea why this occurs?
When I try to connect from my server to the other with PuTTY, everything works fine

Have a good day!

Comment: What version of ssh are you running on the server? If v1, upgrade. See: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57062

Comment: I use the version 0.11 (SSH-2.0-libssh2_0.11)

Comment: Version 0.11 dates back to dec 2008 http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2, I suggest updating. Run `ssh -V` on the linux server and see if it has a recent version for ssh installed. if not, update as well. Version 1 of SSH has severe security risks.

Comment: The version of PHP on the Windows server is still in 5.1.6. Can I update the libssh anyway? Is there compatibility problem between the library and the php version?

Comment: https://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2/0.13 ssh2 1.0 and above is PHP 7 only. To install a version that is PHP 5 compatible you can run 'pecl install ssh2-0.13' which suggests you should be able to use 0.13 with any PHP5 version. But keep the current DLL for in case it doesn't work

Comment: I'll try this and come back to say if it worked or not. Thanks for your help! And just to be sure, when you say "Version 1 of SSH", it's for the libssh 0.xx or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem when trying to access a focal ubuntu server from a little old xenial through ssh2_connect. The solution was to update libssh2-1. Even with php showing the old version, it worked normally.

In the xenial, I added the focal repository, then installed the latest version of libssh2-1, restarted PHP to apply and removed focal repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt -y install libssh2-1
sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse"
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: It took me many hours, but I finally found your comment and it was the resolution to my issue as I knew it would be once I read it, but I never would have guessed otherwise.  Thanks very much for posting this comment!!  I owe you a beer!

Comment: This solved my problem. @pdropi Could you format your answer so it is clearer to understand the different steps?

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But I have a question.
You updated the SSH Library libssh2 on your client using PHP that's right...?
And with wich version of PHP...?

Answer (score 4):

> Warning: ssh2_connect() [function.ssh2-connect]: Error starting up SSH connection(-5): Unable to exchange encryption keys in ../aff_wifi.php on line 203

libssh2 0.x only supports Diffie-Hellman SHA1 based key exchange. OpenSSH has disabled DH SHA1 by default. That leaves libssh2 0.x high and dry.

**Option 1: Update libssh2**

libssh2 1.7 and up supports DH SHA256 and ECDH key exchange. These will work with the latest OpenSSH. 1.x releases require PHP 7.

**Option 2: use phpseclib**

If you're stuck on PHP 5 then libssh2 isn't usable. The highest version available for PHP5 is libssh2 0.13 which still only supports the SHA1 key exchanges. An alternate library that worked for me was [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib). That supports diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 and I was able to connect to updated OpenSSH servers.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the SSH server, and the SSH server is running on a Linux system, the **/var/log/messages** and **/var/log/secure** logs on the Linux system might contain events that could be helpful in identifying why "Unable to exchange encryption keys" is being returned.  For example, the /var/log/secure log could have something like this.

```
Jan 29 07:02:46 docker1 sshd[3245780]: Unable to negotiate with 192.168.0.15 port 55736: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]
```

Notice in this example that the /var/log/secure log captures "no matching host key type found" as the underlying issue. By default, the PHP ssh2_connection functions offers the following host key types.

- ssh-rsa
- ssh-dss

If the SSH server does not accept ssh-rsa or ssh-dss as host key types, then the /var/log/secure log will capture something like "no matching host key type found" and PHP should log "Unable to exchange encryption keys". In this scenario, the SSH server would need to be updated to accept the ssh-rsa or ssh-dss host key types.

For example, if the SSH server is OpenSSH, this could mean appending ssh-rsa and ssh-dss to the HostKeyAlgorithms line in the **/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensshserver.config** on the OpenSSH Linux System.

Comment: The log might also be `/var/log/auth.log` on ubuntu